# write arabic language in text box

Tags: php, arabic

I want to create application which will be transliteration of same, arabic to english. (by convert I mean writing roman arabic to roman english)

For that I need user input in arabic in Text area. IF user writes in particular text area it should automatically write in arabic only.

see this example: https://translate.google.com/#ar/en/%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86

How this can be done?

My ultimate goal is performing  Arabic Romanization using Beirut System

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "convert"? Translation or converting transliterated arabic to arabic script?

Comment: What did you try? how it was? and where is the code. AND WHAT was t he problem

Comment: @Othman: I did not get any help, I just started with this and as no clue I got from google I posted here

Comment: @aross: no translate, just convert. just like this https://translate.google.com/#ar/en/%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86

Comment: Question still unclear. Do you want the user to input arabic or latin script? And should the output be translation or tarnsliteration?

Comment: @user123 right, transliteration from arabic to latin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arabic is relatively easy to transliterate to Latin script. There are a few widely used standards for this, which are mostly 1-on-1 mappings of the arabic character to a latin character. They are mentioned here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Arabic

The [PECL intl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) package has transliteration support. If you can't use that, you can have a look at the excellent [Drupal Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module for a PHP implementation (I suggest you download 7.x-3.2, scroll down the page to find it).

Answer (score 1):

- You will need a code that will translate the arabic to english. In PHP

This can be done using language processing. This is a really big topic we, and it's not classified as a problem. Or you can use an API such as Google Translate to get the translation back.

- You will need one text area and one container that will hold the translation.
- You will need an AJAX code that will send to the server the current content of the text area, and get back the translation.
- The trigger should be `onKeyUp`